# c source code file containing more lines

Tags: c

Usually when we are coding we are suggested to limit the number of lines in a source code file. We are not allowed to make a source file too long. What are the reasons for this?

Is there a **technical reason** or it just for **good readability** ?

Comment: People use to limit the size of the code for readability; However, it is a good practice to build small funcitions in order to easily debug the code. It is also a good idea to use small functions to enhance reusability.

Answer (score 1):

If your whole program is one source file, then this restriction seems kind of silly.  But when you are allowed to break it up into multiple files, then this may be a ham-handed way to force you to break things up into logical pieces, which helps keep things organized and, for really large projects, can speed up builds (as not all files will need to be re-built every time) and facilitate dividing the work between multiple people.